# Python-OpenCV digit segmentation

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

For my image processing class, I picked the digit recognition project by myself. In this project the aim is to recognize the digits on the analogue water-gas meters. My first aim is to find , where the digits are located and draw a rectangle on them. Later I want to take the rectangle image and apply machine learning on it to recognize digits. Currently I am stuck on digit segmentation part. What are your suggestions ?

[image: Sample Image]

```
import cv2
import imutils
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
from imutils import contours
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('/Users/USER/Desktop/digitSegmentation/picture2.jpg')

# Grayscaling
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Image blurring
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

# Thresholding
ret, thresh_img = cv2.threshold(img, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Canny edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 200, 255)

cnts = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
displayCnt = None

for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)

    if len(approx) == 4:
        displayCnt = approx
        break

thresh = cv2.threshold(edges, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (2, 6))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_blue = np.array([50, 50, 0])
upper_blue = np.array([120, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)




img_rect = cv2.rectangle(img, (384, 0), (510, 128), (0, 255, 0), 3)


cv2.imshow('Original image', img)
cv2.imshow('Gray image', gray)
cv2.imshow("Threshold image", thresh_img)
cv2.imshow('Edged image', edges)
cv2.imshow('Rectangle drawing', img_rect)
cv2.imshow('kernel',kernel)
cv2.imshow('Thresholding with Canny',thresh)
cv2.imshow('Masked image',mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you add an expected output image?

Answer (score 0):

i need more explanation / context to give ou an appropriate answer. can you provide more images?
a general approach would be to use an ocr (like tesseract,it's easy to use and you can use it in opencv) to find an occurrence of five digits, a comma then 3 digist and cube meter units.
this will also give you the bounding box around (maybe it will be detected as separate words, so you will probably need a merging step.)

if you really want to make some kind of segmentation to find the black area an approach could be to binarise the image with a simple threshold, close the object with a bit of morphological closing and select the area with the appropriate statistique (is area in a good range? shape look's like a rectangle? is there 11 white area inside? etc...) but i think it's more difficult to set up than using tesseract

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find key points on meter used to locating digit area. Such as **template match** using SURF feature.
Then, crop digit area and using detect method to detect digits.